# How to read a file into a shell script as a variable?

Tags: bash, shell

I need to write a shell script to read a text file in and perform operations on it to count all distinct words in the text file.

I have all of the commands needed to do these operations, but how would I go about inputting the text file into the shell script to then use through the commands?

so a command that I use is this, how would i go about having the text.txt as a variable so that I can just call the variable in the script?

```
tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' < text.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple [command substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst):

```
variable=`cat text.txt`
echo $variable
```

Or in bash:

```
variable=$(cat text.txt)
```

Same with:

```
variable=`tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' < text.txt`
```

Answer (score 1):

Tools like tr and wc can operate on files; you don't *have* to pass strings to their stdin. To answer your question:

> how would I go about having the text.txt as a variable so that I can
>   just call the variable in the script?

The syntax for that is:

```
input=text.txt # or other file name
tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]' $input
```

Answer (score 0):

Example file

```
foo
        bar
    foo bar
foobar f0o b@rred
```

Generated via

```
echo -e 'foo\n\t\tbar\n    foo bar\nfoobar f0o b@arred' | tee -a /tmp/foo.bar
```

File continence in bash variable (*short-hand* for `$(cat file)`)

```
v="$(</tmp/foo.bar)"
```

Use variable as input (stripped of non-printable characters) for another command

```
sed 's#@#a#; s@0@o@' <<<"${v//[![[:print:]]]}" | tail -1
```

Should output the last line, replacing `@` with `a` and `0` with `o`

```
foobar foo barred
```

Also one my wish to look into `mkfifo`... best of luck with text.txt parsing.